# How do I change the login logo URL and hover title?

Tags: wp-admin, child-theme, bloginfo

I am trying to change the login logo URL and hover title. I am using the code below but `return bloginfo('url');` and `return bloginfo('name');` aren't outputting the desired `href` and `title`. I'm also using a child theme if that matters at all. What do I need to use instead of `return bloginfo('url');` and `return bloginfo('name');`?

```
/* ==  Change Logo URL ==============================*/

function my_url_login(){
    return bloginfo('url');
}
add_filter('login_headerurl', 'my_url_login');


/* ==  Change Logo URL Hover Text ==============================*/
function my_url_login_hover(){
     return bloginfo('name');
}
add_filter('login_headertitle', 'my_url_login_hover');
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try these filters instead

```
// changing the logo link from wordpress.org to your site
function mb_login_url() {  return home_url(); }
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'mb_login_url' );

// changing the alt text on the logo to show your site name
function mb_login_title() { return get_option( 'blogname' ); }
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'mb_login_title' );
```

Though if you're on a Network/MultiSite you might need [`network_home_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_home_url) instead

Comment: No problem, glad it worked!

Comment: The filter `login_headertitle` is deprecated since WordPress 5.2.0, use `login_headertext` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do is simply paste the codes below in your theme’s functions.php file:

1. Custom Login URL :

   ```
   add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'codecanal_loginlogo_url' );
   function codecanal_loginlogo_url($url) 
   {
     return 'http://www.codecanal.com'; 
     /* Put your desired custom URL here */ 
   }
   ```
2. Site URL :

   ```
   add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'codecanal_loginlogo_url' ); 
   function codecanal_loginlogo_url($url) 
   {
     return home_url(); 
     /* User will be redirected to the site home page */
   }
   ```

For more detail visit following blog :
http://www.codecanal.com/change-login-logo-url-wordpress/